# How to compute loss gradient w.r.t to model inputs in a Keras model?

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, neural-network

What I want to achieve is to compute the gradient of cross entropy with respect to input values `x`. In TensorFlow I had no troubles with that:

```
ce_grad = tf.gradients(cross_entropy, x)
```

But as my networks grew bigger and bigger I switched to Keras to build them faster. However, now I don't really know how to achieve the above? Is there a way to extract cross entropy and input tensor from `model` variable that store my whole model?

Just for clarity my `cross_entropy` is:

```
cross_entropy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(labels = y_, logits=y_conv))
<tf.Tensor 'Mean:0' shape=() dtype=float32>
```

and `x`:

```
x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape = [None,784])
<tf.Tensor 'Placeholder:0' shape=(?, 784) dtype=float32>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We can write a backend function to do that. We use `K.categorical_crossentropy` to compute the loss and use `K.gradients` to compute its gradient with respect to model inputs:

```
from keras import backend as K

# an input layer to feed labels
y_true = Input(shape=labels_shape)
# compute loss based on model's output and true labels
ce = K.mean(K.categorical_crossentropy(y_true, model.output))
# compute gradient of loss with respect to inputs
grad_ce = K.gradients(ce, model.inputs)
# create a function to be able to run this computation graph
func = K.function(model.inputs + [y_true], grad_ce)

# usage
output = func([model_input_array(s), true_labels])
```

Comment: Thanks, @today. What exactly is labels_shape?

In my case I have `model.output`:

    <tf.Tensor 'dense_5/Softmax:0' shape=(?, 10) dtype=float32>

so I gave `shape = (10,)` but it throws some Type Error:

    TypeError: List of Tensors when single Tensor expected

Comment: @A.Newski The output shape of your model. For example, in case of classification model on MNIST dataset it would be probably `(10,)`.

Comment: @A.Newski Oh sorry, I made a small mistake. In `K.gradients` it must be `model.inputs` and not `[model.inputs]` since `model.inputs` is already a list itself. I  corrected this in my answer. And the same for `K.function`.

Comment: Shouldn't then it be `grad_ce = K.gradients(ce, model.inputs)` ?

Comment: Perfect timing :) Thanks!